# Android Virtual Device remains black after starting

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

This is my first question here in stackoverflow. I am new to android development. I am watching some tutorial videos so i can learn. Well i created one `AVD` with ***android 5.0.1***. Through the tutorials i created one simple app that add or subtract. When i start my `AVD` the only thing that creates is a new window which is black, no matter how much time do u give it. I read several topics about this problem but nothing helped me![enter image description here][1]. I also used the "`Use Host GPU`" but nothing changed except than appeared a grey android logo. What can i do so i can use the `AVD`?

Comment: Use RAM size 512 MB. It would work.

Comment: provide an image of the configuration u are making while creating your avd

Comment: How do you start your AVD? From the Virtual Device manager, or by running your app? If you start your AVD without running your code, your AVD will have nothing to show. Make sure to run your code once your AVD is set up.

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey Unfortunately I cant provide any image cause i am new here. Well i can tell u what i input in settings. 
Device: Nexus 5
Target: Android 5.0.1
CPU: Intel Atom (x86)
Skin: HVGA
Front Camera: None
Back Camera: None
RAM: 512(as i have been told above)
Internal Storage: 200

Comment: @Marta Guys thank you so much for your help and your time. My AVD started but i didnt undestrand with what settings did it work. Thank you!!

Comment: what is the specifications of your pc ?